# Passing a string in Html.ActionLink in MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have completed the MVC Music Store application, and now am making my own modifications for practice, and also to prepare me to do similar tasks in my job.

What I have done, is create a view that displays the current list of users. I have done this as I want to be able to change the passwords of users should they forget them. Here is a snippet from my view:

```
<% foreach (MembershipUser user in Model) { %>

<tr>
    <td><%: Html.ActionLink(user.UserName, "changeUserPassword", 
        "StoreManager", new { username = user.UserName }) %></td>
    <td><%: user.LastActivityDate %></td>
    <td><%: user.IsLockedOut %></td>
</tr>

<% }%>
```

What I want to know, is it possible to pass the username through the actionlink as I have done above. I have registered the following route in the global.asax.cs file, however I am unsure if I have done it correctly:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminPassword", //Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{username}", //URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "StoreManager", 
        action = "changeUserPassword", 
        username = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

Here is my GET action:

```
public ActionResult changeUserPassword(string username)
{
    ViewData["username"] = username;

    return View();
}
```

I have debugged through the code to find that ViewData["username"] = username doesn't populate so it looks like either I have not registered the routes properly, or I simply cannot pass the username using the actionlink like I have.

I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong method signature, I think you're using [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx)

You want to do

```
Html.ActionLink(user.UserName, "changeUserPassword", 
    new { controller = "StoreManager", username = user.UserName });
```

Or you can do

```
Html.RouteLink(user.UserName, "AdminPassword", 
    new { username = user.UserName });
```